# boto3 set marker for kms list_aliases() command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-kms

Some of the AWS accounts I'm using have a lot of KMS keys that have aliases tied to them.

My problem is that if the [list_aliases()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.list_aliases) command returns too many results, the results are truncated and the script fails if the value it's searching for is beyond the truncation point.

I tried this to get 200 results back, but it did not work:

```
alias_list = (kms_client.list_aliases(Marker='200')
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidMarkerException: An error occurred (InvalidMarkerException) when calling the ListAliases operation: Could not deserialize marker '200'
```

How do I set the marker for the list_aliases() command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, per the documentation list_aliases returns 1 to 100 results. This is set using Limit, not Marker.

Example:

```
alias_list = (kms_client.list_aliases(Limit=100)
```

Second, results beyond the first 100 require using the Marker value that is returned by the first call to `list_aliases()`. Below is a simple example of how to get the marker and use it to get the next 1-100 values.

Disclaimer, this code doesn't actually do anything with the retrieved aliases and I've not tested it.

```
def get_kms_alias(kms_client, limit=100, marker=""):

    if marker:
        alias_request = (kms_client.list_aliases(Limit=limit, Marker=marker))
    else:
        alias_request = (kms_client.list_aliases(Limit=limit))

    print(alias_request["Aliases"])
    alias_truncated = alias_request["Truncated"]

    if truncated in "True":
        marker = alias_request["NextMarker"]
        get_kms_alias(kms_client, limit, marker)

    return None
```

Comment: Life saver! Thank you :)